# Update an array column to value of another text column in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a Postgres database table, I have an existing text column `post_ids` with values like `["", "1", "2"]`. Now added a new column of type text and array.

```
add_column :pages, :post_ids_new, :text, array: true, default: []
```

In a migration I'm trying to migrate all the values from `post_ids` to `post_ids_new`

```
Page.update_all("post_ids_new = post_ids")
```

Got this error because the new column is of type text array:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "post_ids_new" is of type text[] but expression is of type text

You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Is there any way to migrate those values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running `Page.update_all("post_ids_new = post_ids")` in the console by running `rails console`.

Or if you application is running on Heroku, you can run the console by `heroku console`.

If you want to test the command in a development environment before you do it on your production environment, you can backup your database by running `pg_dump --clean database_name > database_backup_file` and restore your back up by running `psql database_name < database_backup_file`